# Time complexity of nlm-package in R?

Tags: r, time-complexity, big-o, non-linear-regression, systemfit

I'm estimating a Non-Linear system (via seemingly unrelated regressions - SUR), using `systemfit` (`nlsystemfit()` function) package with 4 equations, 32 parameters to estimate (!) and 412 observations. But my code is taking forever (my laptop it's not a super-powerful one tho). So far, the process was on a 13 hours run. I'm not an expert in computational stuff, but someone explained me some time ago the concept of Time Complexity of the algorithms (or big-o), then depending on this concept the time to compute a certain algorithm could rely on specific functional relation on the number of observations and/or coefficients.

Hence, I'm thinking of just stopping my process, and trying to simplify the model (temporarily) and trying to run something simpler, only to check-up if the estimated parameters had sens so far. And then, run a whole model.

But all this has a sense if I can change key elements in my model, which can reduce the time of processing significantly. That's why I was looking on google about the time complexity of `nlm`-package (`nlsystemfit()` function relies on `nlm`) but unsuccessfully. So, this is my question: Anybody knows where I can find that info, or at least give me advice on how test non-linear systems before run a whole model?

Comment: Sorry to hear your process has been running for over 13 hours. With only 412 observations, I would guess the fitting would happen quicker. If it was me, I would re-start and `microbenchmark` my code - maybe 1 equation and 8 parameters, then 2 and 8, then 1 and 16 - to get a feel for the limits and maybe find some optimization or tweaks (ex. `solvtol=`, `maxiter=`).

Comment: Thank you @M.Viking, that's a really good starting point.

Comment: Provide the model or a reproducible example of the same. Jumping into computation for an entire dataset/model is not a wise step - you must benchmark your code (function/algorithm) from a modular extent and move incrementally if runtime is reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't provide any substantial information regarding your model or some code for the same, its hard to express a betterment for your situation.

From what you said:

> Hence, I'm thinking of just stopping my process, and trying to simplify the model (temporarily) and trying to run something simpler, only to check-up if the estimated parameters had sens so far. And then, run a whole model.

It seems you require **benchmarking** or to obtain the measured time taken to execute, as in your case. (although it can deal with memory usage or some other performance metric as well)

There are quite a few ways to benchmark code in R, which include the use of `Sys.time()` or `system.time()` just before and right after your algorithm/function executes, or libraries such as `rbenchmark` (which is a simple wrapper around the `system.time` function), `tictoc`, `bench` and `microbenchmark`.

Among these the last two are preferable options, as `bench::mark` includes `system_time()`, a higher precision alternative to `system.time()` and `microbenchmark` is known to be a reliable source to accurately measure and compare the execution time of R expressions/algorithms.